# django File download issue

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, openstack, openstack-swift

I have some files stored on OpenStack Swift(Or any other Storage Systems). And my django application provide browser based GUI for user to download those files from Swift backend:

```
(1) Each file will have a URL such as: http://domain.com/files/file1
(2) User could use browser or any other client program based on HTTP to download files.
```

I have tested with static files download as:

```
def download(request):
    try:
        #TODO
        file_name = 'E:/sample.docx'
        fsock = open(file_name,"r")
        mime_type_guess = mimetypes.guess_type(file_name)
        if mime_type_guess is not None:
            response = HttpResponse(fsock, mimetype=mime_type_guess[0])  
        response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(file_name)         
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + file_name                        
    except IOError:
        response = HttpResponseNotFound()
    return response
```

My questions are:

(1) I could download the file from the download view,but the downloaded file size is always 1k. What's the problem here?

(2) I still have no clue about how to serve the dynamic files download which stored on other Object Storage backend such as OpenStack Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, In Swift Storage uploaded files are like an object. You couldn't specify file path of object storage.

Second, We can download an uploaded objects(files) using python-swiftclient. The sample code are here.

```
    def download(request):
        #Get object(file) using swiftclient
        url = str(request.values['url'])
        token = str(request.values['token'])
        container = str(request.values['container'])
        name = str(request.values['name'])
        header, data = Client.get_object(url, token, container, object_name)

        #Send object data to browser
        result = data
        response = Response(result)
        response.headers['Content-Type'] = content['header']['content-type']
        response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="'+filename+'"'
        return response
```

Hope this is helpful for you. More information go through http://docs.openstack.org/developer/python-swiftclient/swiftclient.html#swiftclient.client.get_object